# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused when run multiple laravel project in Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

- I have 2 Laravel projects, and my structure folder is (i using win10)

```
- docker-compose.yml
- config_projects
  - app1.cnf
  - app2.cnf
- laravel
  - app1 (domain app1.local)
  - app2 (domain app2.local)
```

- Content of docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  web:
    image: nginx
    container_name: webserver_laravel
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/laravel
      - ./config_projects/app1.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app1.conf
      - ./config_projects/app2.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app2.conf
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    image: php:7.2.5
    container_name: php_laravel
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:    
      - ./:/var/www/laravel     
    networks:
      - laravel

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_laravel
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password   
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

networks:
  laravel:
```

- Content of app1.cnf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app1.local;
    root /var/www/laravel/app1/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    charset utf8;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;    

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }    

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
        break;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {  
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

- Content of app2.cnf same app1.cnf just replace app1 by app2
- Content .env in app1

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.56.1 ===> My computer's ip
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=app1 ===> is app2 in app2's env
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

- Run docker-compose up -d --build
- Open app1.local:8080 -> works normally
- Open app2.local:8080 -> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

**What is the problem ? Thanks so much**

Comment: have you create database `app2`? Can you login to DB and check if there are 2 databases, `app1` and `app2`? What DB logs show?

Comment: Yes. Database app2 is already existed.

Comment: and what is in `db` logs?

Comment: Nothing. I don't think there is problem of database. because app1 works normally

Comment: but you got error from sql so you should have some logs in `db` :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you guys. I fixed it. This is problem of Laravel not Docker
I already run many below commands before posted my question on stackoverflow

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan optimize
```

But it do not work. Now i rerun, it works normally. It's so weird